# Issue with grails doWithDynamicMethods in plugins

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

The similar issue is reported on grails-core repository on github. But it is not answering all questions I am having and not working (partially).

[Issue reported on github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9648)

Grails version: 4.0.3

**Project Structure:**

```
Main Project
+---  CommonPlugin
+---  AddonPlugin
```

**Plugin Descriptor Snippet:**

```
class AddonGrailsPlugin extends Plugin {
    ...
    void doWithDynamicMethods() {
        ExperimentService.metaClass.performOperation = { ExperimentCmd cmd ->
            ..
            < METHOD_FUNCTIONALITY >
            ...
            return < RETURN_ELEMENTS >;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And then trying to access method from *CommonPlugin* throws below error.

```
No signature of method: com.test.services.ExperimentService.performOperation() is applicable for argument types: (com.test.commands.ExperimentCmd) values: [com.test.commands.ExperimentCmd@1ab5698]
Possible solutions: performOperation(com.test.commands.ExperimentCmd)
```

Have followed resolution step provided on the link above and added code to plugin descriptor class.

```
ExperimentService.metaClass = GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.getMetaClass(ExperimentService.getClass())
```

But it does not works. So followed the approach to enable `ExpandoMetaClass` globally and it does works perfectly.

Question:

- Any plugin specific solution available to update metaClass to reflect newly added method from `doWithDynamicMethods()` or the only solution is to enable ExpandoMetaClass globally?

Comment: FYI... Of the 3 questions, "Why ExpandoMetaClass is been disabled globally from grails 3?", "Will it be harmful to enable it for all the plugins in the application?" and "Any plugin specific solution available to update metaClass to reflect newly added method from doWithDynamicMethods()?"... the 3rd question is the one that is most appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: Question updated.